# ALSA installation error: does not match kernel/arch

Tags: 14.04, sound, kernel, alsa, dkms

I had problems with my headphones and speakers working at the same time and I am trying to install ALSA. I downloaded it from https://code.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ubuntu/alsa-daily/+packages

I am running a 14.04 Ubuntu, I have dkms installed and this is the build error:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i oem-audio-hda-daily-lts-utopic-dkms_0.201603031720-ubuntu14.04.1_all.deb
Selecting previously unselected package oem-audio-hda-daily-lts-utopic-dkms.
(Reading database ... 319426 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack oem-audio-hda-daily-lts-utopic-dkms_0.201603031720-ubuntu14.04.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking oem-audio-hda-daily-lts-utopic-dkms (0.201603031720~ubuntu14.04.1) ...
Setting up oem-audio-hda-daily-lts-utopic-dkms (0.201603031720~ubuntu14.04.1) ...
Loading new oem-audio-hda-daily-lts-utopic-0.201603031720~ubuntu14.04.1 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.19.0-51-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 3.19.0-51-generic
Error!  The dkms.conf for this module includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which
does not match this kernel/arch.  This indicates that it should not be built.
Done.
```

Comment: I don' t think you need to install ALSA manually because it would normally already be part of the installation. Maybe you can check out `alsamixer`, a great cli tool that was able to save me multiple times. Especially when it seemed I couldn't change the audio volume. Otherwise, maybe explain what are the things you are trying to do and/or programs you are using.

Comment: well, I have alsamixer and it helps... some but my main problem is basically for a totally different question, I want to see if this ALSA helps.. if not I will be forced in makin another question

Comment: ok, I am running a 64-bit system but I can't seem to find 64-bit installer can you please tell from where can I get the 64-bit one ? Make an answer if you wish

Comment: Looks like those packages are i386 and you (or your system) is trying to build for amd64 (x86_64). This might be the problem and looks like it is what the error is trying to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would be much easier to add the PPA. This will make installing and also updating a breeze.

https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-audio-dev/+archive/ubuntu/alsa-daily

You can add a PPA in the terminal or check out software sources and edit those.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/add-apt-repository

Good luck!

Comment: I am new in linux what should i type in the terminal, it's not sudo add-apt-repository..